# Lauch screen storyboard with tab bar skeleton

Tags: ios, xcode, storyboard, splash-screen

Similar to the [launch screen HUG example](https://developer.apple.com/design/human-interface-guidelines/launching#Launch-screens), I want to create a skeleton with a tab bar for the launch screen.

[image]

The app itself is just a capacitor wrapper, but it's recreating the iOS tab bar. I'm fine with not having any tab bar items shown and I tried dragging the `Tab Bar` view to align with at the bottom, but it's never shown correctly on both home indicator as well as home button devices. If it looks right on the iPhone 14, the iPhone SE looks like this:

[image]

If it looks right on the iPhone SE, it looks like this on the 14:

[image]

I'm assuming that's happening because I'm using the tab bar as an element and the proper way would be to use the `Tab Bar Controller`, but is that the right approach for the splash screen?

Answer (score 0):

Using a `Tab Bar Controller` worked fine, although I'm not sure if that's the correct approach.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<document type="com.apple.InterfaceBuilder3.CocoaTouch.Storyboard.XIB" version="3.0" toolsVersion="21701" targetRuntime="iOS.CocoaTouch" propertyAccessControl="none" useAutolayout="YES" launchScreen="YES" useTraitCollections="YES" useSafeAreas="YES" colorMatched="YES" initialViewController="9BE-Ju-foE">
    <device id="retina6_12" orientation="portrait" appearance="dark"/>
    <dependencies>
        <deployment identifier="iOS"/>
        <plugIn identifier="com.apple.InterfaceBuilder.IBCocoaTouchPlugin" version="21679"/>
        <capability name="Named colors" minToolsVersion="9.0"/>
        <capability name="Safe area layout guides" minToolsVersion="9.0"/>
        <capability name="System colors in document resources" minToolsVersion="11.0"/>
        <capability name="documents saved in the Xcode 8 format" minToolsVersion="8.0"/>
    </dependencies>
    <scenes>
        <!--View Controller-->
        <scene sceneID="XTr-DS-Hbo">
            <objects>
                <viewController id="MA7-lE-pUF" sceneMemberID="viewController">
                    <view key="view" contentMode="scaleToFill" id="WUt-pb-Y5b">
                        <rect key="frame" x="0.0" y="0.0" width="393" height="769"/>
                        <autoresizingMask key="autoresizingMask" widthSizable="YES" heightSizable="YES"/>
                        <viewLayoutGuide key="safeArea" id="iMq-5i-RNU"/>
                        <color key="backgroundColor" systemColor="systemBackgroundColor"/>
                    </view>
                    <tabBarItem key="tabBarItem" title="" id="idv-bW-W7C"/>
                </viewController>
                <placeholder placeholderIdentifier="IBFirstResponder" id="cen-rO-Uok" userLabel="First Responder" customClass="UIResponder" sceneMemberID="firstResponder"/>
            </objects>
            <point key="canvasLocation" x="519" y="-34"/>
        </scene>
        <!--Tab Bar Controller-->
        <scene sceneID="kYe-wT-zvR">
            <objects>
                <tabBarController id="9BE-Ju-foE" sceneMemberID="viewController">
                    <tabBar key="tabBar" contentMode="scaleToFill" insetsLayoutMarginsFromSafeArea="NO" translucent="NO" id="Bro-oq-ylq">
                        <rect key="frame" x="0.0" y="0.0" width="393" height="49"/>
                        <autoresizingMask key="autoresizingMask"/>
                        <color key="backgroundColor" name="tabBarColor"/>
                        <color key="barTintColor" name="tabBarColor"/>
                    </tabBar>
                    <connections>
                        <segue destination="MA7-lE-pUF" kind="relationship" relationship="viewControllers" id="aKN-A2-3jI"/>
                    </connections>
                </tabBarController>
                <placeholder placeholderIdentifier="IBFirstResponder" id="2IT-PP-U7D" userLabel="First Responder" customClass="UIResponder" sceneMemberID="firstResponder"/>
            </objects>
            <point key="canvasLocation" x="-538" y="-35"/>
        </scene>
    </scenes>
    <resources>
        <namedColor name="tabBarColor">
            <color red="0.96862745098039216" green="0.96862745098039216" blue="0.96862745098039216" alpha="1" colorSpace="custom" customColorSpace="sRGB"/>
        </namedColor>
        <systemColor name="systemBackgroundColor">
            <color white="1" alpha="1" colorSpace="custom" customColorSpace="genericGamma22GrayColorSpace"/>
        </systemColor>
    </resources>
</document>
```